# Ways to earn money in GTA SA

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I was playing GTA SA for some time, but the main problem for me was earning money. I either cheated or murdered to get money, sometimes completed missions.
But I want to ask, what are the ways to earn money in GTA SA, except murder, cheating and horse races hack?